# What is Control and Perception?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've just started crafting and gathering classes and I've noticed that the equipment in my quest rewards tend to have the following stats: +Gathering, +Crafting, +Perception, and +Control. +Gathering and +Crafting are pretty self-explanatory, but what do +Perception and +Control do? Is there any one that I should focus on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control increases the amount of HQ quality improvements when using actions like Basic Touch / Rapid Touch and so on. The amount of quality points an item needs to have a 100% High Quality chance depends on the item level.

Perception increases the change of a High Quality item being obtained while gathering, although without special circumstance or specific actions this will not go above 15%, and some items don't /have/ a HQ variant to be gathered.

For a full list of the various attributes and how they affect your character, see [here](http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Attributes).